# instrument dalvik in android occur register limitation within v0~v15

Tags: android, dalvik, instrumentation

recently ,i am try to profiling android application path, and while i using path profiling algorithm i need to instrument the dalvik instruction for satisfying more scalable application analysis .
but now i am encounter an  inevitable problem in register limitation.
during my instrumentation work , i need at least 8 register addition, but in a method ,there is typically limit the number of register within v0~v15, and i will trigger recompilation error if I direct modify the '.locals x'block. 
typically like this.

```
.method public static mixCir(I)Ljava/lang/String;
.locals 10
.parameter "max"
```

and if we just modify 10 --> 18 , the apktool compilation will trigger error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jf.util.PathUtil.getRelativeFile(PathUtil.java:44)
    at org.jf.smali.smaliFlexLexer.getSourceName(smaliFlexLexer.java:292
    at org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream.getSourceName(CommonTokenStre
ava:345)
    at org.antlr.runtime.Parser.getSourceName(Parser.java:88)
    at org.jf.smali.smaliParser.getErrorHeader(smaliParser.java:358)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.displayRecognitionError(BaseReco
er.java:192)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.reportError(BaseRecognizer.java:

    at org.jf.smali.smaliParser.smali_file(smaliParser.java:736)
    at brut.androlib.mod.SmaliMod.assembleSmaliFile(SmaliMod.java:71)
    at brut.androlib.src.DexFileBuilder.addSmaliFile(DexFileBuilder.java

    at brut.androlib.src.DexFileBuilder.addSmaliFile(DexFileBuilder.java

    at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.buildFile(SmaliBuilder.java:64)
    at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:48)
    at brut.androlib.src.SmaliBuilder.build(SmaliBuilder.java:35)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildSourcesSmali(Androlib.java:222)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildSources(Androlib.java:179)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:170)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:154)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:182)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:67)
```

so, is there any approach to satisfy my requirement ?
thanks a lot!